# Change the Store state in NGRX

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm writing unit tests in order to test the functionality of my NGRX store (Angular 10, NGRX 10).

Currently I am using actions to set the state the way I want it; then I am executing the action I want to test and checking that it modifies the state to what I expect.

Is there a way to bypass the first step by explicitly setting the state of the NGRX store to a known value, so I can then execute the action under test? The docs don't seem to give me anything.

In answer to comments:

1. Setting an initial state doesn't work. The store is only created once for all the tests, and so the state doesn't get initialized for each test. Also it doesn't get initialized before any effects are executed, only before the reducers are executed.
2. I'm aware of approaches like testing the parts of the Store separately, but I would rather avoid them.

Comment: Maybe an obvious question.. but are you using mockstore https://ngrx.io/api/store/testing/MockStore ?

Comment: I'm not, because I'm testing the Store, not testing the components that use the store. MockStore doesn't function like Store.

Comment: Probably I don't understand well the question, I am sorry, but can't you simply initialize your store with an initial state?

Comment: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#setting-the-initial-state should be all you need to initialize your scenario, all the best

Comment: The store doesn't seem to be recreated for each test, they seem to be shared. So initialState doesn't guarantee that each test starts how I want.

Answer (score 1):

NGRX's actions do not require testing. They're just simple objects without any logic.
What does need testing is the reducer functions. And the easiest right way to do that is to export these functions and test them directly.

For example, let's say that this is your reducer:

```js
export type State = {
  count: number;
  label: string;
};

export const initialState: State = {
  count: 0,
  label: 'anonymous'
};

const _counterReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(increment, (state) => ({...state, count: state.count + 1})),
  on(setLabel, (state, {label}) => ({...state, label })),
);

export function counterReducer(state, action) {
  return _counterReducer(state, action);
}
```

What I suggest is to extract and export the reducer functions. Something like this:

```js
export function incrementReducerFn(state: State): State {
  return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
}

export function setLabelReducerFn(state: State, {label}: {label: string} ): State {
  return { ...state, label };
}

const _counterReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(increment, incrementReducerFn),
  on(setLabel, setLabelReducerFn)
);
```

And then, test them directly:

```js
describe('counter reducers', () => {
  it('incrementReducerFn', () => {
    // Arrange
    const original: State = {
      count: 0,
      label: 'anonymous'
    };

    // Act
    const actual: State = incrementReducerFn(original);

    // Assert
    expect(actual.count).toBe(1); // the reducer works
    expect(actual.label).toBe(original.label); // the reducer doesn't change other properties
    expect(actual).not.toBe(original); // the original state is immutable
  });
});
```

Comment: I've seen this approach widely used. However I'm not very happy with it. What I would like to do is test the Effects and Reducers together - in other words "When I dispatch this action with the Store in this state, I expect it to change to this state." I dislike testing the two parts separately - I've seen too many cases of software where each part works according to their spec, but together they don't do what they should.

Comment: Also I'm aware that the *actions* are simple enough not to require testing. What I want to test is the combination of Effects and Reducers. They have to work together to do the thing i want, and I want to check that they do it.